# Windows File security, removing an access rule

Tags: c#, windows-security, directory-security

I have the following code, that should remove the access of users from a certain folder.  Unfortunately it doesn't (the access rule remains in place).  No exception is thrown.

```
AuthorizationRuleCollection arc = ds.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));

foreach (FileSystemAccessRule ar in arc)
{
    if (ar.IdentityReference is NTAccount)
    {
        NTAccount account = ar.IdentityReference as NTAccount;

        if (!AdminUsers.Contains(account.Value) &&
            ownerAccount != account.Value)
        {
            ds.RemoveAccessRule(ar);
            WriteLog("Removed rule for: " + account);
        }

     }
}

outputDirectory.SetAccessControl(ds);
```

I can see from my logs that the RemoveAccessRule was called.  Why isn't the rule gone?

**Edit:** The rule is an inherited rule.  Do I need to do something different to remove inherited rules?

Comment: is there a parent folder that is enforcing the rule you are trying to remove?

Comment: It is inherited if that's what you mean...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [SetAccessRuleProtection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection.aspx) on `DirectorySecurity` class, from reading it..I would think you'd need..

```
ds.RemoveAccessRule(ar);
ds.SetAccessRuleProtection(true,false);
```

play around with it.

Comment: I do believe that was it exactly.  It's wonderful, many thanks.